# How to apply scopes to joins in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say i've established this associations:

```
class Budget
  has_many :forfeitures
  scope :with_forfeitures, ->{ joins(:forfeitures) }
end

class Forfeiture
  belongs_to :budget      
  scope :between, ->(from, to) { where("created_at > ? AND created_at < ?", from, to)}
end
```

Now i can do this:

```
Budget.with_forfeitures.where("forfeitures.created_at > ? AND forfeitures.created_at < ?", from_date, to_date)
```

But notice that i had to write my `between` scope in raw sql.

Can i instead do something like `Budget.with_forfeitures.between(from_date, to date)` but in that way that `between` applies to forfeitures? If i can't do that, how do i achieve the same result without duplicating my `between` scope in raw sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to write `Budget.joins(:forfeitures).merge(Forfeiture.between(from, to))`

So, `merge` method should work for you.

I'd suggest you to watch [episode 215](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) and [episode 239](http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough) from railscasts.com

Comment: denis-bu, terrific! Though `merge` worked for me, but & didn't.

Comment: remove code with &. can't get it to work either :) maybe it is deprecated